# Solidity test case to check "withdraw" function in a contract?

Tags: solidity

I want to write a test case to check if my `withdraw` function works correctly. The code looks like this:

```
function withdraw(uint _amount, address _to) public onlyAuthors {
  require(!isNullAddress(_to));
  require(_amount <= this.balance);

  _to.transfer(_amount);
}
```

But in a test case, it looks like `this.balance` or `[some_address].balance` are not available. Is there any good way to test this kind of function in a unit test?

Answer (score 0):

1) make a contract factory:

```
import web3 from './web3';
import contractFactory from './build/ContractFactory.json';

const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(
  JSON.parse(contractFactory.interface),
  '<address of deployed contract>'
);

export default instance;
```

2)In your test you new up a contract and do the required actions to get the balance in a state that you want to test against. In your test file:

```
const compiledFactory = require('../ethereum/build/ContractFactory.json');
const compiledContract = require('../ethereum/build/Contract.json');

beforeEach(async () => {
  accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  factory = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(compiledFactory.interface))
    .deploy({ data : compiledFactory.bytecode })
    .send({ from : accounts[0], gas : '1000000' });
  factory.setProvider(provider);

  await factory.methods.createContract('100').send({
    from : accounts[ 0 ],
    gas : '1000000'
  });
```

ect.  This step will vary according to your contract.

3)Try to interact with the contract(E.G. attempt to withdrawal more than the amount you are allowed or whatever.  Then expect the behavior you are testing for.

Comment: Thank you. I meant to ask that `instance.balance` is not available since it's a private property/function.

Comment: Right but if I am a user or entity who is authorized to withdrawl, and I expect there is 5eth in the contract, I can try to withdraw 6eth and expect for it to fail.  then withdraw 5 eth and expect my account balance to go up by 5.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `web3.eth.getBalance(address)` to retrieve contract balance.